# Why do elements transition discretely between solid, liquid and gas forms, rather than existing as a spectrum?

Tags: intermolecular-forces

I don't understand what makes a liquid entirely different from a gas, why wouldn't a liquid slowly become more gaseous, but instead transition completely from one form to the other?

Comment: Well, it would, if you'd walk around the critical point.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37088/why-must-both-the-critical-temperature-and-pressure-be-exceeded-to-achieve-the-s

Comment: The title is not very defining. Not all spectra are continuous; plenty are flat-line spectra.