# Isothermal compression at critical temperature

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose I am compressing a gas isothermally at its critical temperature. Initially, it has a large volume. I start compressing it and reach the critical point. At this point, the gas will start to form liquid and both of these phases cannot be distinguished, right? Now if I further compress it isothermally at its critical temperature so that the pressure reaches beyond critical pressure, what will my gas look like? Will it be a liquid or a gas or something in between, I don't know. Is there a video where I can see something of this sort? Just curious

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37088/why-must-both-the-critical-temperature-and-pressure-be-exceeded-to-achieve-the-s

Answer (score -1):

https://youtu.be/RmaJVxafesU?t=242

carbon dioxide has a critical point at 31 degrees celsius.