# Liquifying a gas above critical temperature

Tags: temperature, pressure

Is there any theoretical/hypothetical way through which a gas can be liquified above critical temperature? For example applying inifinjte amount of pressure to the system?

Comment: Already well answered here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37179/79678. Also, applying infinite pressure would force the poor gas to become a black hole! ;-)

Comment: At the critical point, both liquid and gas have the same density, which is $\pu{0.34 g/mL}$ for water. So at this point the limit between liquid and gas simply disappears. At higher pressures and higher temperatures, your stuff can be considered as made of a liquid or of a gas.